# Showing Draft and Pending Posts with WpGraphQL

Tags: wordpress, graphql, wp-graphql

I am using the [wpgraphql plugin](https://www.wpgraphql.com/).  For the most part, it is working.  However, I can only query posts whose status is `published`.  Posts with a status of `pending` or `draft` do not show up.

In other words, here is my query:

```
query MyQuery {
  newsArticles {
    nodes {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

If I set the status of my articles to `pending` or `draft`, then nothing shows up.  If I set them to `published` then they do show up.

Note, it does not make any difference if I try a different post type (like `posts`) or do the query uses `edges`, like this:

```
query MyQuery {
  newsArticles {
    edges {
      node {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results are the same.

So, any idea how to return results regardless of the status?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/325#issuecomment-572694522 ?

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

WPGraphQL, by default, only allows public posts to be queried because that is how WordPress works, i.e., only public posts are visible to users.

The first few steps are to add some authentication over our `graphql` queries so that non-public posts can be queried.

1. Download this - https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-jwt-authentication WordPress plugin either by cloning the repo in `plugins` directory or uploading the zip file via WordPress.
2. After the above step, you should be able to see the plugin in your plugins section. Don't activate the plugin now.
3. Add `define('GRAPHQL_JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'secret_token');` to your `wp-config.php` file which is present in the `/var/www/html` folder. This secret key is used by the plugin to generate tokens to access non-public posts. Ensure the secret token is some random long string that should only be accessible to the WordPress server.
4. Activate the plugin, and query the following

```
mutation LoginUser {
  login( input: {
    clientMutationId: "uniqueId",
    username: "your_login",
    password: "your password"
  } ) {
    authToken
    user {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

You will receive a token that you can use from your code to query non-public posts.

Once the above steps are done, the only thing left is how to use the token and get the non-public posts in your code.

1. Add `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1` in your `.htaccess` file, which is present in the `/var/www/html` directory. If you haven't updated your `.htaccess` file before, it should look like below after updating it. This enables the `Authorization` header on the incoming request on the WordPress server. We will use the `Authorization` header to send the authenticated token.

```sh
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

2. Once the above step is done you will be able to send an `Authorization` header and get non-public posts

```js
Authorization: Bearer ${your_token}
```

Replace `${your_token}` with your actual token, and you will now be able to query non-public posts.